# VTK, Mayavi BUG: all `ButtonReleaseEvents` fail, yet all `ButtonPressEvents` work?

Tags: python, events, mouseevent, vtk, mayavi

### I want to capture `mouse release` events in a mayavi figure. Specifically, I need to click an object, rotate it, and then receive an input on mouse release.

---

**Attempt:**

The standard mayavi `on_mouse_pick` can not detect such behavior (see `approach 1` in the code below).

However, vtk (which mayavi is built on) *DOES* have a specific `LeftButtonReleaseEvent()` function. This knowledge was found at:
https://www.vtk.org/doc/nightly/html/classvtkRenderWindowInteractor.html

I've written a code below that uses this online document effectively, and can call a similar function from that list: `LeftButtonPressEvent()` (see `approach 2` below). While the `LeftButtonPressEvent()` works, somehow `LeftButtonReleaseEvent()` does not (and the same for Middle, Right clicks).

I've been racking my brain for days - does anyone understand this outside of it being a straight bug? Can anyone test on their own computers to make sure?

```
from __future__ import print_function
import numpy as np
from mayavi import mlab
from tvtk.api import tvtk

###################
### mayavi section:

fig1 = mlab.figure(1)
mlab.test_contour3d()
mlab.title('click me')

##############
# approach 1:
#def picker_callback(picker_obj):
    #print('click recieved')   
#fig1.on_mouse_pick(picker_callback)

##############
# approach 2:
def press_callback(vtk_obj, event):
    print('pressed')
def release_callback(vtk_obj, event):
    print('released')

fig1.scene.interactor.add_observer('LeftButtonPressEvent', press_callback) #works
fig1.scene.interactor.add_observer('LeftButtonReleaseEvent', release_callback) #doesn't work

mlab.show()
```

Comment: are you sure you want to call something on mouse release? "pick" callbacks are called when you release the mouse button (without moving it after you pressed it)

Comment: @FelipeLema this fact got me excited, and was a great idea, but it turns out it only works if there is no mouse movement in between mouse-on and mouse-off. What i need is for the user to grab on to an object (mouse-on), rotate it, and then release (mouse-off), upon which the plot needs to undergo a command.

Comment: @FelipeLema I've updated my approach from the ground up and edited my initial post - the code is now as simple as possible with a direct error isolated. Do you have any insights that may help?

Comment: You should try `EndInteractionEvent` instead of `LeftButtonReleaseEvent`. Source: https://github.com/enthought/mayavi/blob/9eff3b12d37e1574916be649e8c487d7f7b160f7/mayavi/core/mouse_pick_dispatcher.py#L110

Comment: @FelipeLema THANK YOU!! Amazing help, I've updated with an answer that provides a full solution, while ignoring all other events (such as zooming, etc.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks so much to @FelipeLema in the comments for this awesome answer! I've combined his suggestion into the previously written code to simulate natural `mouse release` events:

```
from __future__ import print_function
import numpy as np
from mayavi import mlab
from tvtk.api import tvtk

###################
### mayavi section:

fig1 = mlab.figure(1)
mlab.test_contour3d()
mlab.title('click me')

click_on = 0

def press_callback(vtk_obj, event):
    global click_on
    click_on = 1
    print('pressed')

def release_callback(vtk_obj, event):
    global click_on
    if click_on == 1:
        print('released')
        click_on = 0

fig1.scene.interactor.add_observer('LeftButtonPressEvent', press_callback)
#fig1.scene.interactor.add_observer('LeftButtonReleaseEvent', release_callback) #doesn't work
fig1.scene.interactor.add_observer('EndInteractionEvent', release_callback) #solution!! (with above setup)

mlab.show()
```